# How to set fish as default shell in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, fish

I installed fish and can start it. Now I would like to use it as my default shell in Cygwin. How may I achieve this?

So far I tried two thing. I overwrote the content of `/etc/shells` with `/bin/fish` and with `/usr/bin/fish` then restarted. That did not work. The sometimes suggested application of `chsh` fails b/c this program is not available also not for additional installation.

Comment: This answer looks more accurate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363210/set-default-shell-in-cygwin/37815158#37815158

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit */etc/passwd* with your favorite editor and change the last column (ie. where you see /bin/bash now) with /bin/fish.

This is basically what chsh does at the end of the day, but done manually.